# Are Array's & Objects the only non-primitives in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing a lot of research on this topic for over 2 weeks now and I'm only asking the question because [MDN's documentation on mutability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable) says only arrays and objects are not primitive values and of course that's true, they have reference values.

However, I thought **functions**, **string object**, **Date**, and **RegEx** also had reference values because they are also non-primitives. 
For example if we use slice() on a string primitive, javascript will automatically convert(reassign) it to a string object and now it's mutable as the word 'snow' becomes 'know' through reassignment. This won't work with `const` because it disables reassignment.

```
let word = 'snow'
console.log(word) // "snow"
word = `k${word.slice(1)}`
console.log(word) // "know"
```

So I'm guessing either MDN is wrong or a lot of other resources like [dotnettricks](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/javascript/datatypes) and even a few javascript certifications guides are wrong...

Answer (score 2):

MDN isn't wrong - functions, Date and RegEx **are** objects.

Also, string is still primitive.

```js
let a = 'snow';
let b = a;
a = 'know';
console.log(b); // snow
```

Comment: functions are callable objects.

Comment: They're still objects.

Comment: In this example, b isn't a "reference" to `a`, but rather assigned the current value a? When `a` is reassigned, the value doesn't update because it's stored by the value, not by reference?

I guess what I'm confused about then is how the string object wrapper works and references. A string is primitive but it has a string object wrapper. Slice isn't available on the primitive so, at runtime, the language uses the wrapper object and swaps the letter?

But let's say we use the sting object directly:
```
const str = new String('The quick dog.')
str.slice(-5) // dog.
console.log(str) 
```

Comment: `b` isn't a reference to `a`, because in JavaScript you can't have references to strings. Also, your code logs "The quick dog.". It's not going to work, string is in all ways a primitive.

Comment: Thar's not helpful, or relevant to my question. 
You just re-explaining what I just explained -_-

Moving away from the String object wrapper, because that's still primitive.
What about function, date and RegEx because they are according to MDN also objects so it would reason that they are by-reference instead of by-value?

Comment: Date is definitely by-reference (try `setFullYear`), RegExp also is by-reference (you can check that by setting its `lastIndex` property and checking the other reference). Functions should be by reference though I can't find a property I can write to.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. MDN isn't wrong so much as they just don't distinguish between by-value as primitives and by-reference as non-primitive, which is what I was doing. 

Then MDN avoid talking about all instances of object except array... 
Also Function, Date, Array and String is an instance of `Object`. 
Finally, where I got confused is that the String object is still primitive even though it is an instance of object.

Does that sound about right even though we cannot directly check for by-value vs by-reference?

Comment: Now that I check `new String()` seems to be really an object, but most functions don't mutate it. String literals are primitive but `new String()` is an object while `String("str")` is not.

Answer (score 1):

"strings" is primitive and new String("strings") is an object but in both cases the sequence of characters is immutable.

in your example you didn't really mutate the string you just create a new string and assign it to the same variable

```
var primitiveString = 'hello';
var objectString = new String('hello');
var objectStringRef = objectString;

// string are primitives so you can not add properties to it
primitiveString.newProperty = "my property";

console.log(primitiveString.newProperty) // undefined

// You can add properties to String objects
objectString.newProperty = "my property";

console.log(objectString.newProperty) // "my property"

// and you can have a reference to a String object
console.log(objectStringRef.newProperty) // "my property"

// but both are immutable
primitiveString[0] = "p";
objectString[0] = "p";

console.log(primitiveString) // "hello"
console.log(objectStringRef.toString()) // "hello"
```

Comment: yeah, exactly. Well, it still mutates but the mutation only happens through reassignment which is why `const` doesn't work, it disables reassignment and throws a type error. 
The more weird part is on the browser when you inspect a String object it says primative type regardless of the literal '' or new String().

Also `String instanceof Object // true` and `Array instanceof Object // true` yet one is a reference and the other isn't. A bit confusing until I understood it as just constructors != reference value.

Comment: @HansDev to be a mutation the object should be the same after the change but that is not the case. it is just a plain reassignment. using const instead of let will probably demonstrate it more easily. you can assign an array to a constant and change its content (mutate) const A = [1, 2, 3]; A.pop(); console.log(A)//[1, 2]; there is no way you can do the same to a string.